# How to know the applet mode in Siebel Open UI

Tags: siebel

Does Siebel Open UI have a way of knowing the mode of an applet. For instance `Query Mode`, `Edit Mode` or `New Mode` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method in siebel open ui with which you can get the mode of the current applet..

```
SiebelApp.S_App.GetActiveView().GetApplet("Applet_Name").GetMode();
```

this will return the mode of current applet

Answer (score 2):

If you are in an event context and cannot access the PM, you can try looking for active controls that are only active/visible in specific modes.

Here is some generic code I use to confirm no applets in the view are in Query Mode, by confirming there are no Go/ExecuteQuery buttons with a specific class visible:

```
var eQueryBtnCount = $("body").find(".siebui-icon-executequery").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).length;

if (eQueryBtnCount < 1) {
    // Do Something that is not available in Query Mode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BC have a flag to identify if the applet is in query mode or not.

```
pm.Get("GetBusComp").IsInQueryState()
```

This will give you a true or false. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a method in Siebel OpenUI for getting the applet mode:

```
this.GetPM().Get("GetMode");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pm.Get("GetMode");
pm.Get("IsInQueryMode")
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by describing what is different about your solution from the other answers that are quite similar. What is is specifically that you are suggesting here ? Read more about how to improve answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer